# Infinite Loop when merging two sorted Linked List

Tags: c#, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I'm running into an issue where the last node in a linked list is replicated repeatedly.

- Parameter List1 = [1,2,4]
- Parameter List2 = [1,3,4]
- Expected Result = [1,1,2,3,4,4]
- Actual Result = [1,1,2,3,4,4,4,4,4,4,...]

Something happens in the final else statement before the return that duplicates the 4 multiple times and I can't figure out what it is. What is causing the the final node to behave like this? Is it a problem with my SinglyLinkedNode Class?

before `current.next = list2` is executed the values are

- current = [1,1,2,3,4]
- list2 = [4]

after it is executed the values are

- current =  [1,1,2,3,4,4,4,4,4,..]
- list2 =  [1,1,2,3,4,4,4,4,4,...]

```
public static SinglyLinkedNode MergeTwoSortedLists(SinglyLinkedNode list1, SinglyLinkedNode list2)
{
    //if one list is null, return the other
    if (list1 == null) return list2;
    if (list2 == null) return list1;

    //declare the result node; declare the node that you will fill
    SinglyLinkedNode result = new SinglyLinkedNode();
    SinglyLinkedNode current = result;

    //while neither lists are empty
    while (list1 != null && list2 != null)
    {
        //do the comparisons and populate the current Node;
        if (list1.val <= list2.val)
        {
            current.next = list1;
            list1 = list1.next;
        }
        else
        {
            current.next = list2;
            list2 = list2.next;
        }
        current = current.next;
    }
    //when one list is empty, use the remaining list to fill the current node
    if (list1 != null)
    {
        current.next = list1;
    }
    else
    {
        current.next = list2;
    }
    
    return result.next;
}

public class SinglyLinkedNode
{
    public int val;
    public SinglyLinkedNode next;
    public SinglyLinkedNode(int val = 0, SinglyLinkedNode next = null)
    {
        this.val = val;
        this.next = next;
    }
}
```

Comment: I ran your code as-is and got the result: `1 1 2 3 4 4`. Just what you say you are expecting. No recurring 4's and no infinite loop.

Comment: Perhaps you could add how you are initialising the parameters passed in to the function...Show us how you assign and setup `list1` and `list2`

Comment: Thank you for your comment on how I set up the parameters. I definitely made a mistake there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a mistake when initializing the parameters because
I had a list2 node point to a list1 node.

Answer (score 0):

### First, and Must important concept

When you use the following code don't clone the Object, and clone the object's pointer. And in line 2 causes `current.next` referenced to `list1.next` after assignment.

```
 1- current.next = list1;
 2- list1 = list1.next;
```

---

But you can change your code like.

1- update your object `public class SinglyLinkedNode : ICloneable` and implement this method.

```
public class SinglyLinkedNode : ICloneable
{
    // other code
    public object Clone()
    {
         return new SinglyLinkedNode(val, null);
    }
}
```

2 - change here

```
//when one list is empty, use the remaining list to fill the current node
if (list1 != null)
{
    current.next = list1;
    list1 = list1.next;
}
else
{
    current.next = list2;
    list2 = list2.next;
}
```

---  Here, we have a nice [example](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/rawatgaurav/merging-two-sorted-linked-lists-in-C-Sharp/)